# Bash Case always goes to default

Tags: linux, bash, switch-statement

I am trying to parse some arguments in a bash script with the following code:

```sh
for arg in "$@"
do
    case $arg in
        -i|--initialize)
        SHOULD_INITIALIZE=1
        shift # Remove --initialize from processing
        ;;
        -r|--root)
        ROOT_DIRECTORY="$2"
        shift # Remove argument name from processing
        shift # Remove argument value from processing
        ;;
        *)
        echo "Error, Invalid argument $arg"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done
```

However, when calling the function as expected

```sh
bash script.sh -i -r /some/directory
```

The result is always

```sh
Error /some/directory
```

It seems like the "/some/directory" string is reentering the switch statement. Isn't that the whole purpose of the shifts? I am not that well versed in Bash, so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try to add another `shift` in between `esac` and `done`

Comment: @Jetchisel Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately it did not work, I still see the same behavior :(

Comment: @jpcr3108 : The `-i` is fine, but you don't remove the argument for `-r` and on the next round of the loop it will be recognized as invalid. IMO, doing a `for` loop is a poor choice for handling arguments to flags. Maybe a `while` would be better. You can stick with `for`, but after having seen `-r` you have to set a flag which causes on the next iteration the argument to be ignored.

Comment: @jpcr3108 : One thing I don't understand in your question, is that you talk about _calling the function_. There is no function in your code. Are you only posting part of the relevant code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shift` doesn't affect what value will be assigned to `arg` next, because the `for` loop effectively "freezes" the set of values to iterate over.

Use a `while` loop instead:

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case $1 in
        -i|--initialize)
        SHOULD_INITIALIZE=1
        shift
        ;;
        -r|--root)
        ROOT_DIRECTORY="$2"
        shift # Remove argument name from processing
        shift || { echo "Error, no root directory given"; exit 1; }
        ;;
        *)
        echo "Error, Invalid argument $1"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Unlike the `for` loop, the `while` loop re-evaluates its condition at the start of each iteration, which includes re-evaluating the value of `$#` after any previous shifts.

Note that `shift` will fail if there is no argument to shift, so you can use its exit status to check if `$2` actually existed.

Comment: `$arg` should be `$1`

Comment: Since it's `bash` I suggest using `[[ ... ]]` or `(( $# > 0 ))` to not have to call `test`.

Comment: Hey @chepner thanks for the answer. What you say makes total sense, and it does solve the issue. However, I am curious, when would you say is better to use the `for` approach with `$@` ? I just ask because i see it in some tutorials, and i dont believe my issue is that rare

Comment: @jpcr3108 You can use `for` if you're not depending on the changes you make to the variable you're iterating over (`$@` in this case).

Comment: The `for` loop only lets you consume one argument per iteration, while `-r` requires you to consume more than one. Use `for` when you want to treat each argument uniformly (though not necessarily identically).